# How to cast a process and use it

Tags: c#, process, casting, ms-word

I am trying to find a process, microsoft word, and then cast it to word.Application.

I've tried this

```
    private word.Application findWord()
    {
        foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (process.ProcessName == "WINWORD")
            {
                return (word.Application)process.Site;
            }
        }
        return new word.Application();
    }
```

,but it returns with a null
I have had no luck so far...

Answer (score 2):

The word.Application class isn't a Process, but a Automation object. Those aren't the same.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558830(v=office.14).aspx

How to automate Microsoft Word to create a new document by using Visual C#
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316384

Comment: Thanks, but I am asking for how to get an opened microsoft word application and using it in my application. The second link just shows me how to open a new word doc.

Comment: You could look over here: _How to use Visual C# to automate a running instance of an Office program_ http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316126

Comment: Thank you jeroen, that was perfect.